# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

trying to make the bot run ,installed everything needed , and still something is wrong

```
import discord
import random

TOKEN = 'xxx'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user]'.format(client))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shahar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\bin\dis_bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client'
```

Comment: Why is your file in `Lib\site-packages\discord\bin`? It's not normal to put your project files inside the folder for a library that's within that project's environment. Anyway, the reason you could be getting that error is because Python is importing something called `discord`, but it's not the right module. This usually happens when you have another file within your script's folder that has the same name as the module you're trying to import. So, make sure there's not another file called `discord.py` in that folder. And I also suggest putting the project files in the project folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but I use `bot.event`

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot is online')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

try using and if you have errors ask!

[@Haymon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17502483/haymon)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem is most likely that you put your file in the wrong directory. Try putting it in C:\Users\[yourusername]\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv

This is so it can import discord properly, it is most likely importing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I was playing around with `pycord` and the `discord` modules, it was fixed by doing:

```
pip uninstall discord.py discord py-cord
pip install discord
```